# Как вызвать onFailure в библиотеке pdfviewpager:library?

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Мне нужно остановить загрузку Pdf когда я закрываю activity .
https://github.com/voghDev/PdfViewPager

Для остановки кода

////

```
 public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements DownloadFile.Listener {
        
            LinearLayout root;
            RemotePDFViewPager remotePDFViewPager;
            Button btnDownload;
            PDFPagerAdapter adapter;
            ProgressBar progressBar;
        
            private Vibrator Vibro;
        
            public String loadUrl ="Тут будет ссылка";
    
            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                finish();
            }
        
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
        
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.page_loading, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.remote_pdf_root);
                    btnDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_download);
                onClick(null);
            }
        
            @Override
            protected void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
        
                if (adapter != null) {
                    adapter.close();
                }
            }
    
            public void showDownloadButton() {
                btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        
            public void updateLayout() {
                root.removeAllViewsInLayout();
                root.addView(progressBar,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                root.addView(btnDownload,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                root.addView(remotePDFViewPager,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        
                Vibro = (Vibrator)this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                Vibro.vibrate(50);
        
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "мы тут ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
        
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String url, String destinationPath) {
                adapter = new PDFPagerAdapter(this, FileUtil.extractFileNameFromURL(url));
                remotePDFViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                updateLayout();
                showDownloadButton();
            }
        
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showDownloadButton();
            }
        
            @Override
            public void onProgressUpdate(int progress, int total) {}
        
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Context ctx = this;
                final DownloadFile.Listener listener = this;
                remotePDFViewPager = new RemotePDFViewPager(ctx, loadUrl, listener);
                remotePDFViewPager.setId(R.id.pdfViewPager);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Отключить интернет в процессе загрузки?

Comment: Хорошо , как отключить интернет + wifi и при этом (только в моем приложении ?)

Comment: Возможно, вам надо точнее сформулировать задачу. Возможно, вы хотите как-то программно, по нажатию кнопки, остановить ранее начатую загрузку файла? Если да, то надо смотреть есть ли такая фича в библиотеке. Если не знаете как её искать - добавьте в вопрос ссылку на библиотеку вместе с раскрытием деталей задачи

Comment: Библиотека pdfviewpager:library:1.1.0 нужно при закрытии activity  остановить загрузку pdf

Comment: Указывать библиотеку лучше всего ссылкой на исходники оной. Это радикально сокращает её поиск для тех, кто может захотеть вам помочь. И делать это лучше  в самом вопросе, не в комментариях. Также в вопрос стоит добавить и то, что вам нужно сделать. Иначе - те кто вопрос увидят не смогут сходу понять в чём у вас проблема и что за библиотеку вы используете. Вопрос можно править через специальную кнопку: [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1169470/edit). Сделайте это - и я вам напишу какие варианты есть для решения этой задачи)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Встроенной в библиотеку возможности такой нет.

Однако есть возможность передать в конструктор `RemotePDFViewPager` свою реализацию интерфейса `DownloadFile`, в которой можно такую возможность реализовать.

Например можно сделать как-то так (дополненная, нетестированная и неидеальная копия `DownloadFileUrlConnectionImpl`):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class DownloadFileUrlConnectionImpl implements DownloadFile {
    private static final int KILOBYTE = 1024;

    private static final int BUFFER_LEN = 1 * KILOBYTE;
    private static final int NOTIFY_PERIOD = 150 * KILOBYTE;

    private Thread thread;

    Context context;
    Handler uiThread;
    Listener listener = new NullListener();

    public DownloadFileUrlConnectionImpl(Context context, Handler uiThread, Listener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.uiThread = uiThread;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void download(final String url, final String destinationPath) {
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                InputStream in = null;
                FileOutputStream fileOutput = null;
                try {
                    File file = new File(destinationPath);
                    fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    URL urlObj = new URL(url);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
                    int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                    int downloadedSize = 0;
                    int counter = 0;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_LEN];
                    int bufferLength = 0;
                    in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                    while ((bufferLength = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        if (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
                            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                            counter += bufferLength;
                            if (listener != null && counter > NOTIFY_PERIOD) {
                                notifyProgressOnUiThread(downloadedSize, totalSize);
                                counter = 0;
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new InterruptedException();
                        }
                    }

                    notifySuccessOnUiThread(url, destinationPath);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    notifyFailureOnUiThread(e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    notifyFailureOnUiThread(e);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.d(DownloadFileUrlConnectionImpl.class.getSimpleName(), "Thread interrupted!");
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (in != null) {
                            in.close();
                        }
                        if (urlConnection != null) {
                            urlConnection.disconnect();
                        }
                        if (fileOutput != null) {
                            fileOutput.close();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    public void stopDownload() {
        thread.interrupt();
    }

    protected void notifySuccessOnUiThread(final String url, final String destinationPath) {
        if (uiThread == null) {
            return;
        }

        uiThread.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listener.onSuccess(url, destinationPath);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void notifyFailureOnUiThread(final Exception e) {
        if (uiThread == null) {
            return;
        }

        uiThread.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listener.onFailure(e);
            }
        });
    }

    private void notifyProgressOnUiThread(final int downloadedSize, final int totalSize) {
        if (uiThread == null) {
            return;
        }

        uiThread.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listener.onProgressUpdate(downloadedSize, totalSize);
            }
        });
    }

    protected class NullListener implements Listener {
        public void onSuccess(String url, String destinationPath) {
            /* Empty */
        }

        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            /* Empty */
        }

        public void onProgressUpdate(int progress, int total) {
            /* Empty */
        }
    }
}
```

Добавьте этот файл себе в проект и используйте так:

```
DownloadFileUrlConnectionImpl d = DownloadFileUrlConnectionImpl(this, new Handler(), this)
remotePDFViewPager = new RemotePDFViewPager(ctx, d, loadUrl, listener);
```

Когда вам надо будет остановить загрузку - вызовите метод остановки так:

```
d.stopDownload();
```

Вызвать его можно, например в методе `onStop()` активити.

Comment: мне нужно создать класс ?

Comment: Да, всё верно. Класс, реализующий интерфейс из библиотеки

Comment: Ругается  на new Handler(),

Comment: У вас есть метод `onClick`, в нём строка `remotePDFViewPager = new RemotePDFViewPager(ctx, loadUrl, listener);` - вот её и заменить на код из комментария.

Comment: `Ругается на new Handler()` - это непонятно. Напишите что именно происходит - приложение падает, или код не компилируется. И в обоих случаях надо написать что именно у вас в логах или в ошибке компилятора пишется. Часто в сообщении сразу предлагается решение проблшемы.

Comment: Красным написано  alt+entr   api <30 platform

Comment: Попробуйте тогда такое: `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`, вместо `new Handler()`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112160/discussion-between--and-).

Comment: @Алена, мне в чате неудобно(

Comment: давайте  тогда тут

Comment: @Алена, как я понимаю, у вас получилось? И проблема была в импорте `Handler`?

Comment: Да практически , я поставила  minSdkVersion 30 и нажала alt+enter а потом вернула назад свой minSdkVersion . И работает - но вот только остановить не могу если сразу написать d.stopDownload(); то все работает . Но в onBackPressed() ругается  не может найти d.

Comment: Наверно не понимает  где взять d.stopDownload();

Comment: @Алена, тут дело в области видимости переменных. Вам надо вынести объявление переменной (`DownloadFileUrlConnectionImpl d`) на уровень класса активити - так переменная будет видна во всех методах.

Comment: я поняла после public class MainActivity2 а что нужно написать (DownloadFileUrlConnectionImpl d) или как это правильно пишется?

Comment: Надо объявить переменную в классе. Вместо `DownloadFileUrlConnectionImpl d` в методе напишите только `d`. А `DownloadFileUrlConnectionImpl d;` - поместите в начало класса.

Comment: Спасибо  вам большое за помощь все работает . Хотелось последнее узнать класс (DownloadFileUrlConnectionImpl) сильно отличается от стандартного ?

Comment: @Алена, пожалуйста) Нет, отличий не много. Я просто вынес Thread из библиотечной реализации в отдельную переменную, создал метод для прерывания потока и сделал обработку прерывания потока в процессе считывания файла из потока. Там в сумме строк на 10 отличий.